# The scancode shown by dmesg is different from that from showkey

Tags: linux, keyboard

I'm using Debian Jessie with LXDE on a recent notepad. The command "showkey -s" prints "0xe0 0x4c 0xe0 0xcc" when Fn+F2 is pressed. But dmesg tells me:

```
atkbd serio0: Unknown key released (translated set 2, code 0xab on isa0060/serio0).    
atkbd serio0: Use 'setkeycodes e02b <keycode>' to make it known.
```

Two questions:
1. Where the scancode e02b comes from?
2. Why the command `setkeycodes e02b 44` works but not `setkeycodes e04c 44`?

I also noticed that when I press Fn+F2, "evtest" prints 'ab':

```
    Event: time 1481025600.385595, type 4 (EV_MSC), code 4 (MSC_SCAN), value ab   
    Event: time 1481025600.385595, -------------- EV_SYN ------------value 1    
    Event: time 1481025600.394373, type 4 (EV_MSC), code 4 (MSC_SCAN), value ab    
    Event: time 1481025600.394373, -------------- EV_SYN ------------
```

The command

```
    setkeycodes ab 44
```

works too. Can someone help me understanding what's wrong?
Thank you all.

**EDIT**:
Both Fn+F2 and Fn+F3 have the same scancode (0xab) for evtest and dmesg, but showkey prints two different scancodes:

```
0xe0 0x4c 0xe0 0xcc    for Fn+F2    
0xe0 0x54 0xe0 0xd4    for Fn+F3
```

I wonder where the scancode 0xab printed by evtest comes from.

Comment: Yes, the scancode shown by dmesg is different from that from showkey. That's just the way things are.

Comment: Sorry, that link didn't help. My questions are still unsolved.